# проблема с TextView изменяю часть строки Android

Tags: android, строки, textview

есть ресурс

```
<string name="s_result">$%s% Result</string>
```

есть TextView в котором будем менять часть текста вот так

```
textViewres1.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.s_result), 0));
```

по идее с начала там ставим 0, затем в коде меняем на результат вычисления, но приложение закрывается с ошибкой, что я делаю не так?

Comment: первое, что вы точно сделали не так - в вопросе нет стектрейса при возникновении ошибки, а без него, видимо, вам придется самому гадать, что еще может быть не так ..

Comment: так же, если вы делали попытки решить вопрос самостоятельно, то приведите его в актуальное состояние (ресурс, код и ошибка, которую он выдает), чтобы отвечающие не тратили время на решение проблемы, которой нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример ресурса:

```
<string name="welcome_messages">%1$d new messages.</string>
```

В джаве:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String text = res.getString(R.string.welcome_messages, mailCount);
```

Comment: изменил на %d ,  та же беда (((
сделал <string name="s_result">%d Result</string>

Comment: изменил на %d ,  та же беда (((
сделал  '<string name="s_result">%d Result</string> '
и изменил 'textViewres1.setText(getString(R.string.s_result, 0)); '

Comment: @Dmitri Ivanov, обновил ответ

Comment: cделал <string name="s_result" formatted="false">%d Result</string>
проблема не исчезла, что-то я делаю не так.

Comment: а если не `false` а `true`?)

Comment: пробовал не работает, может еще идеи будут?

Comment: обновил ответ..

Comment: вот ошибка которую выдает

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: ru.startandroid.calcapp, PID: 3576
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.startandroid.calcapp/ru.startandroid.calcapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
      
.....
Application terminated.

Comment: тьфу блин! в вас ТекстВью = null Проверьте находите ли вы его вообще и правильный ли id

Comment: спасибо, причина была в этом, но вопрос есть такой, я юзал БуттерКнайф , все как в мануале сперва текствью нашел через него
'  @BindView(R.id.textViewres1)     TextView textViewres1; '
потом 
'  ButterKnife.bind(this);  ' 
Почему он его не нашел, зависимость в грандл я поставил.

Comment: в следующий раз прикладывайте текст ошибки к вопросу.